# Class function click show/hide

Tags: jquery, hide, show

i was starting with `JQuery`, i was trying to make a simple function to define if click, hide one div and show another div.

my code was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#dots').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('#truncated_full_value').show();
  });
  jQuery('#dots').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('#text-before-truncate').hide();
  });
});
```

And the html was:

```
   <dd class="truncated">  
       <div class="text-before-truncate">   
         <a href="#" class="dots" onclick"return flase"> ... </a>  
       </div>

     <div class="truncated_full_value">   
       <dt>Opties</dt>  
     </div> 
   </dd>
```

What i was doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` as a class selector

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.dots').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.truncated_full_value').show();
    jQuery('.text-before-truncate').hide();
    });
});
```

`#` is an id selector. Also, you do not need to attach them in two seperate handlers. You can put both the show/hide in the same handler.

Comment: You can combine them in single event handler

Comment: Holy ...
I was really dumb... Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the event handlers for both:

```
jQuery('.dots').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.truncated_full_value').show();
    jQuery('.text-before-truncate').hide();
});
```

If you want to `toggle`:

```
jQuery('.dots').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.truncated_full_value, .text-before-truncate').toggle();
});
```

Comment: There is no element with id `dots`

Comment: Why two calls to `toggle`? You can join both selectors together in the second case.

Comment: @Satpal Didn't saw that. Thanks! Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

use below code  . you don't need to write separate events for same element. combine both as one event.

There is no element with id `dots` in your HTML. you need to use `.` a class selector like `.dots`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('.dots').on('click', function() {
     jQuery('#truncated_full_value').show();
     jQuery('#text-before-truncate').hide();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You all have class selectors use '`.`' prefix instead of '`#`'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.dots').on('click', function() {
     if(jQuery('.truncated_full_value').is(':visible')){
      jQuery('.truncated_full_value').hide();
      jQuery('.text-before-truncate').show();
     }
     else{
      jQuery('.truncated_full_value').show();
      jQuery('.text-before-truncate').hide();
     }
   });
});
```